# Mosaic two rasters along cutline

Tags: raster, gdal

I have to mosaic several pairs of images (A and B). 
"A", "B" images has the same format (tif), projection, cell size, extent.
Cutline in shape format is available if its needed. 
Nodata values are not present.

Im looking for a scriptable (preferable gdal) solution to do this, but nothing useful found yet.

[image: illustration]

Comment: is gdal_merege what you need? https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html

Comment: I guess not. It cannot handle cutlines.

Comment: You may very well be right, I don't do much with GDAL anymore, but you may be able to specify a no data value (the white space in your example) to be ignored in the mosaicing. The cutline could be irrelevant, no?

Comment: Try gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html `Description
The gdalwarp utility is an image mosaicing, reprojection and warping utility.`

Comment: @Zipper1365 Tried and at the first glance it is okay. But if there is a white pixel on left side of image "A", than it will appear Black on "C". And that's not okay. The images are orthophotos so the burnt out areas have to remain white.

Comment: understood. I'm getting a bit out of my wheelhouse now (been a while since I've been working in imagery production)...All I can think is that you need to be able to reclassify that "no data" area  to differentiate it from white - maybe something you need to specify in teh production/output of A nd B.  GDAL_warp as noted above may allow you you to use a polygon mask to block the no data areas.  that's all i have though...good luck , man!

Answer (score 1):

If you open the tiffs as numpys you can apply any condition you want to them with numpy where.

```
ds = gdal.Open(A)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arrA = band.ReadAsArray()
ds = gdal.Open(B)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arrB = band.ReadAsArray()
arrC = np.where((arrA != <yourwhitevalue>), arrA, arrB)
[cols, rows] = array.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create('{}.tif'.format('C'), rows, cols, 1,gdal.GDT_UInt32)
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())  ##sets same geotransform as input
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())  ##sets same projection as input
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array)
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)  ##if you want these values transparent
outdata.FlushCache()  ##saves to disk!!
outdata = None
band = None
ds = None
```